# Trim function not really trimming

Tags: php, mysql

I am using php; and i read that if i am asking the user to enter some information about himself through a form then when i access that information;i should better use

```
$var=mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc,trim($_POST['name']));
```

as it will delete all the spaces from the text field and other unwanted symbols, but it really is not deleting the spaces?
Help!

Comment: Could you give us an example of the input, the output you're getting, and the output you expect? That would probably help us tell what's going on. But you do realise that [trim()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) only trims stuff from the beginning and end of string, right, not anything in the middle? (i.e. `trim('   this is a test   ')` => `'this is a test'`.)

Comment: It will only delete leading and trailing whitespace. Do you want to remove _all_ spaces?

Comment: `trim` only removes **leading** and **trailing** spaces, not all spaces within the string.

Comment: Trim removes whitespace from the start and end of strings.  What results do you actually get?

Comment: @Pekka, it's mysqli_real_escape_string

Comment: @Matt Gibson - dint know that..thanks..and what about mysqli_real_escape_string; doest it trim from middle and end only?

Comment: I also recommend looking at [prepared statements](http://mattbango.com/notebook/web-development/prepared-statements-in-php-and-mysqli/), they really do save a lot of messing around with escaping.

Comment: @Karan mysqli_real_escape_string simply escapes, it doesn't "trim" anything. It's simply to make the string safe to include in a SQL query, for example by escaping quote marks.

Comment: People can't even be bothered to read the documentation for `trim`. Sad.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`trim()` does not delete ALL spaces, only leading and trailing spaces.

Comment: For trimming non-breaking spaces use:

`trim($matching_image, chr(160)); // 160 is ASCII code for non-breaking space`

Answer (score 3):

For Just Spaces, use $string = str_replace(' ', '', $string); to remove all spaces of string

For white spaces use $string = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $string);

Answer (score 1):

`trim()` will remove from the start and end of the string, [the following](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php):

> 1. " " (ASCII 32 (0x20)), an ordinary space.
> 2. "\t" (ASCII 9 (0x09)), a tab.
> 3. "\n" (ASCII 10 (0x0A)), a new line (line feed).
> 4. "\r" (ASCII 13 (0x0D)), a carriage return.
> 5. "\0" (ASCII 0 (0x00)), the NUL-byte.
> 6. "\x0B" (ASCII 11 (0x0B)), a vertical tab.

In addition, as also noted by @Wesley Murch, in the comments, trim will remove any character you pass to the second argument of the function, too. E.g.

```
$str = 'appHello Worldapp';
$clean_str = trim($str, 'ap'); // as noted by @venimus, use just a single char,
                               // which you want removed
echo $clean_str; // output: Hello World
```

Comment: Note for completion: `trim()` also accepts a second parameter which contains any other characters to trim.

Comment: you should actually use `$clean_str = trim($str, 'ap');` because it does not remove a string but the characters listed `trim($str, 'pa');` does the same

Comment: For trimming non-breaking spaces use:

`trim($matching_image, chr(160)); // 160 is ASCII code for non-breaking space`

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
$var=mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc,str_replace(" ", "", $_POST['name']));
```